# How do I modify individual LED's in this code?

Tags: arduino

good morning!

I wanted to ask if someone can guide me through this code because even if I try, I can't make it work. What I want to do is to be able to change if individual leds illuminate or not. I have a 60 LEDs on my strip. Thank you.

```
  else 
  {
    Serial.println ("Someone Is Infront Of the Sensor");
     for (uint8_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {

    if (i <= secondval) {
      pixelColorBlue = (i + 1) * (128 / (secondval + 1));
      //pixelColorBlue = 255;
    }
    else {
      pixelColorBlue = 0;
    }
    strip.setPixelColor((i + STARTPIXEL) % 60, strip.Color(pixelColorBlue));
  }
  strip.show();
  delay(100);
  }
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce. Have you tried running a simple sketch just to light up each led in turn?

Answer (score 0):

is this Neo ?
you can try the simple

```
void loop() {

 for(int i=0;i<NUMPIXELS;i++){
 // pixels.Color takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0,100,0)); // Moderately bright green
    pixels.show(); // This sends the updated pixel color to the hardware.
    delay(500); // Delay for a period of time (in milliseconds).
  }
}
```